# Proof that $K[x]/(x-1)^2$ is not isomorphic to $((x-1)/(x-1)^2)^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I would like some help proving that the rings $\frac{K[x]}{(x-1)^2}$ and $\frac{(x-1)}{(x-1)^2}\times \frac{(x-1)}{(x-1)^2} $ are not isomorphic. In general the same question bothers me for the case of $\mathbb{Z}_m\times\mathbb{Z}_n$ versus $ \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ when m,n are NOT coprime. I an looking for a smart way to prove that they are not isomorphic when they are considered as rings, not as abelian groups (Z-modules). The first question came to me after reading in Keith-Dennis book "noncommutative algebra" in example 4 p. 38 that "F[x]/(f) is semisimple if f is square free" (in fact I think it should be "if and only if")

Comment: As $K[x]$-modules? What have you tried? You'll get better responses if you include context and your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: I edited the question, I didn't say much at first because it is an easy question and I was looking for an elementary answer. Sorry for being lazy, I am browsing from my cell :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rings it is easy to show these are not isomorphic: $K[x]/(x - 1)^2$ is a ring with unity ($1 + (x - 1)^2$) and $R = (x - 1)/(x - 1)^2\times (x - 1)/(x - 1)^2$ has no $1$. (Every element of $R$ is of the form $((x - 1)p(x) + (x - 1)^2, (x - 1)q(x) + (x - 1)^2)$, where $p,q\in K[x]$. Multiplication of any two such elements always gives $(0 + (x - 1)^2, 0 + (x - 1)^2) = 0_R\in R$.)

As for the $\Bbb Z/(mn)$ vs. $\Bbb Z/(m)\times\Bbb Z/(n)$, you could do casework and grind things out in terms of prime factorizations, but I like this argument better: note that
$$
\Bbb Z/(nm)\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Z/(m)\cong\Bbb Z/(nm,m) = \Bbb Z/(m),
$$
and
$$
(\Bbb Z/(n)\times\Bbb Z/(m))\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Z/(m)\cong\Bbb Z/(n,m)\times\Bbb Z/(m,m) = \Bbb Z/(n,m)\times\Bbb Z/(m).
$$
If the two rings we started with were isomorphic before, they would be isomorphic after tensoring. However, if $(n,m)\neq\Bbb Z$ (i.e., $n$ and $m$ have a common divisor), then the two rings after tensoring are not isomorphic, as they do not even have the same number of elements.